# make element move as mouse moves

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this nifty little thing going right now. It is partially what I am looking for. When you try to run the code, press down on the image and move it with your mouse:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
</style>
<body>




<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/piersolutions/image/upload/v1621772508/mpvovedzx30m3gknvmwi.jpg"></div>
</div>

<script>
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

it works fine, but I want it to basically move wherever my mouse moves. So if im moving my mouse, it should follow my mouse. you can see an example here `www.poolhouse.co` in the header (only works on desktop). How would I do this with the code below? Is it possible?

Comment: Change `onmousedown` to `onmouseover`.

Comment: also not sure what you mean _only works on desktop_ - tablets and mobiles dont have mouseover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change `mousedown` to `mouseover`

```js
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmouseover = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmouseover = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/piersolutions/image/upload/v1621772508/mpvovedzx30m3gknvmwi.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/t2v9n1fk/)

Comment: you're awesome! Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <style>
      #mydiv {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
      }
    </style>

   <body>
    <div id="mydiv"></div>

   <script >
     let pos1 , pos2;
     const ele = document.querySelector('#mydiv');
     ele.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){
     pos1 = e.offsetX;
     pos2 = e.offsetY;
     document.addEventListener("mousemove" , eleMove);
     document.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e){
     document.removeEventListener("mousemove" , eleMove );
   })
 })

  function eleMove(e){
  ele.style.top = (e.clientY - pos2) + "px";
  ele.style.left = (e.clientX - pos1) + "px"
 }
 </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Hello, please add some details about your answer. WHat you changed, why you changed it, etc.